# add $httpBackend and ngmocke2e as dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to add $httpBackend and ngmocke2e as dependency but inside run function

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'myApp.Group', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                redirectTo: '/auth/login'
            });
    })
    .run(function ($rootScope, $window, $location, Environment) {

       if(localhost) {
         //add ngMockE2E and $httpBackend as dependency and call below function
         mockRoutes($httpBackend);
       }

    });
```